# Installing Ubuntu 18.10 on pentium

Tags: 18.10

Can I install Ubuntu on a pentium dual core with 1 gb of ram. If it is not possible please suggest a version. And please tell me, which is the best version of Ubuntu with min errors.

Comment: I used a single core dell d610 (latitude, 1gb ram, pentium m), ibm thinkpad t43 (snigle core pentium m...), and even hp dx6120 (dual core pentium 4, 1.5gb ram - that I then expanded to 3gb mid 18.10 dev.cycle) let alone other like systems for testing Xubuntu 18.10 x86 & Lubuntu 18.10 x86.  Your own tastes will dictate which is best for you, but you can download the ISO, write to usb, and then test.

Comment: If you want to use Qt based gui applications, LXQt used by Lubuntu 18.10 will be best, however if wanting to use GTK+ gui apps, Xubuntu 18.10 is best (or using LXDE and Lubuntu 18.04) given your lack of memory (you don't want to waste your ram by having two sets of libraries in memory...).   Yes you can install other desktops (MATE & other lower-resource hungry desktops run fine on the single-core d610 & t43 I mentioned with Ubuntu 16.04, but with MATE's switch from GTK+2 to GTK+3 I stopped using MATE due to my systems low memory, but it'll depend what you use your system for..)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest LUbuntu. This is a version of Ubuntu with the graphic desktop LXDE/LXQT.

The requirements for this version of Ubuntu is:

- Memory (RAM): for advanced internet services like Google+, YouTube,
  Google Drive, and Facebook, your computer needs at least 1 GB of RAM.
  For local programs like LibreOffice and simple browsing habits, your
  computer needs at least 512 MB of RAM.
- Processor (CPU): the minimum specification for CPU is Pentium 4 or
  Pentium M or AMD K8. Older processors are too slow and the AMD K7 has
  problems with Flash video.

You can obtain more information and download it from: https://lubuntu.net/lubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-released/